# Jenkins pipeline getting error log in slack notification

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, slack, jenkins-groovy

I’m new to jenkins and slack.
I’m trying to integrate the error part of the build logs into my slack build notifications.
I didn't find documentation on how to get logs in the notification, i'm not looking for uploadfile.

Comment: Please elaborate on your requirement. What do you mean by "How to Get logs"? Do you want to send the entire log to slack? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually i just want the error part of my logs in the notification. I tried to copy and download the logs in my workspace and later was planning to get the error part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to do this. As you mentioned you can either read the Jenkins log and try to determine what the error was. A better approach would be to wrap your logic with a try-catch and send the notification in the catch block.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      steps {
        script {
           try {
                sh 'letsGenerateAError'
            }
            catch (error) {
                echo "Error occurred while Running. Message : ${error.getMessage()}"
                slackSend(channel: channel, color: colorCode, message: "Error occurred while Running. Message : ${error.getMessage()}")
                throw error
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```